# Select cells from array UITableView

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uitableview

I have an array of users

```
var selectedUsers = [User]()
```

users are added to this array as they are selected in a UITableView (see screenshot: https://www.dropbox.com/s/uk03mhgi3x4jesy/File%2006-10-2015%2C%2018%2003%2044.png?dl=0)

What I'm having difficulty with is when I press back and then reload the view controller, all the checkmarks disappear.

Is there anyway I can keep track of the selected cells?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You could use a delegate to pass a array between the two viewcontrollers. For example, each time you select a row, you can store the userId's associated with the row, in the array. So if you were to press back and then open the view with the UITableView, before you load the UITableView, you can first check if there is an array being passed to the viewcontroller containing the UITableView / if there is an array, check if the count is greater than 0. If the array is not empty, then use a for loop to cycle through the array of users being displayed with the array being passed containing all of the previously selected id's, then add the check marks that match up to the Id's in the array.

Here is a tutorial that possesses a similar example: http://makeapppie.com/2014/08/04/the-swift-swift-tutorial-why-do-we-need-delegates/

Answer (score -1):

The answer to this question is kinda dependent on what you want the application to do... Do you want the User selections to persist even if the app is closed? If so consider using NSUserDefaults or CoreData. Otherwise store the data somewhere that does not get blown away (maybe the root view controller of your application). You could for instance implement the delegate pattern on the view controller with the table view and pass the values to the container view controller.. Just some ideas.

Answer (score -1):

So you can use class NSUserDefaults to save small amount of data. If you want to have persistent store so you have to use Core Data that helps you store you data with scheme you provide.

If you just want to pass data from one view controller to another view controller so you just need use delegation pattern or you can use method prepareForSegue where you can pass some data as well but you can't store this way, just pass.

If you make your question more detailed you will get more explicit answer.